# How to use C in ROS Or Create Own ROS Package for Existing Code

Tags: ros, opencv2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello Everyone,

I stuck in one problem, I have done lots of work in different lets say C and Matlab, I can convert Matlab program to C. The main problem is How to create Own ROS package such that it can use all existing code, plz tell me in detail (coz i am newbie). How to call C program in ROS or How can I convert C into ROS program easily.
I got one answer somewhere, we can cal from system(), but how I dont know.

**Plz Help me Its urgent**.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/200205/how-to-use-c-in-ros-or-create-own-ros-package-for-existing-code/) by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 67 on 2014-12-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-30**:
Is this a duplicate of [How to create ROS package for Existing C code](http://answers.ros.org/question/200197/how-to-create-ros-package-for-existing-c-code/)?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-30**:
Also:

> **Plz Help me Its urgent**

Is not likely to get you any replies sooner.

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2014-12-31**:
GVDHOOM- I can understand, I guess same problem posted by my colleague also. It will be better if u would give answer rather than finding duplicate questions

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-12-31**:\

> It will be better if u would give answer rather than finding duplicate questions

Please understand that this is all people supporting you in their 'free' time. Moderators are here to make sure the site stays usable, and posting duplicate questions is not acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Calling 'C from C++' is a bit of a non-issue: both are compilable by C++ compilers, provided you take proper care (symbol mangling, etc). This is also not very ROS specific. If you're using Matlab code generators, you should be able to call into that code from a C++ based ROS wrapper. Some links:

- isocpp.org: [How to mix C and C++](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp)
- [How to Call C Function in C++, C++ Function in C (Mix C and C++)](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/01/mix-c-and-cpp/)
- [Call a C function from C++ code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16850992/call-a-c-function-from-c-code)

But again, this is not very ROS specific.

Now if you have an actual *binary*, that is a different matter. As you wrote in the [How to create ROS package for Existing C code](http://answers.ros.org/question/200197/how-to-create-ros-package-for-existing-c-code/), you can execute those using `system()`. I can see two issues with that:

1. [Why system() is evil](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/11153/).
2. Overhead: this is already mentioned by the link under point 1, but as you've tagged your question with `opencv2`, I'm assuming you'll want to do image processing, where processing latency is often undesirable. Starting, executing and stopping a binary for every frame is not going to be very efficient.

A third might be that you're not *really* integrating with ROS that way, and besides basic *input-output wrapping* you won't be able to access any of the nice things ROS can offer.

Btw: Mathworks has released an official [ROS support package](http://nl.mathworks.com/hardware-support/robot-operating-system.html) for Matlab 2012b and up. You might be interested in that as well.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2014-12-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [KDROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/20799/kdros/) on 2015-01-01**:
Thanx gvdhoom, U guided me in right direction. Yes I am using image processing 3D construction, I have done coding in C for that and motion control but Now I want to use everything in ROS, then what should I do? I have to pass input also for motion control command and 3D constructions